# How can I calculate the expectation value of the $N$ variable gaussian integral?

Tags: integration, mathematics

For $N$ variable gaussian integral,

$$I_{N} = \int \prod_{i=1}^{N} dx_{i} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}x_{i}A_{ij}x_{j} +\sum_{i}B_{i}x_{i}} = Ae^{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}B_{i}A_{ij}^{-1}B_{j}}$$

The expectation value of $x_{i}$ is defined as

$$\langle x_{i} \rangle = \frac{1}{I_{N}}\frac{d}{dB_{i}}I_{N} = \frac{d}{dB_{i}}\ln{I_{N}} = \sum_{i}A_{ij}^{-1}B_{j}.$$

I put log on $I_{N}$ and did derivative like

$$\frac{d}{dB_{i}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}B_{i}A_{ij}^{-1}B_{j}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j}A_{ij}^{-1}{B_{j} + \sum_{ij}B_{i}A_{ij}^{-1}\delta_{ij}}\right).$$

The index is confusing. Can we discuss this problem?

Comment: Can you put in a few more steps of your calc?  Also, when you do derivs with indices you need to be careful about using dummy variables as required. You take a deriv w.r.t. $B_i$ when $i$ is one of the summation indices.

Comment: This might be better suited to [math.se]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you consider the first expression, then it follows that $A$ must be symmetric: $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$. (One can show this by relabelling $i\leftrightarrow j$.)

To compute the derivative with $B_i$ it is better to use a new index (say $k$) that is different from those that are summed over, so that
$$ \frac{d B_i}{d B_k} = \delta_{i,k} . $$
Then the last expression becomes

$$ \frac{d}{dB_k} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j}B_{i}A_{ij}^{-1}B_{j}\right)
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j} A_{kj}^{-1} B_{j} + \sum_{i}B_{i}A_{ik}^{-1} \right) = \sum_{i} A_{ki}^{-1} B_{i} . $$